# Django how split durationfield over dates it covers using ORM (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

Using Django (with PostgreSQL) I have a model that represents activities with a certain starting moment (start_datetime) and a duration.

So it is possible that an activity covers more than one day, and I would like to know per activity how much time it covers on consecutive dates (days). So an example would be, all using UTC timezone, to have a 48 hour appointment start on 2022-12-24T12:00, which would have the activity end on 2022-12-26T12:00, giving duration per day:

- 2022-12-24 - 12 hours
- 2022-12-25 - 24 hours
- 2022-12-26 - 12 hours

And I would like to get this information for up to a year's worth of activities, for a single person's calendar.

Is this possible, and if so does anyone have an example of how to achieve this? Ideally I would also be able to specify the timezone that this data needs to be determined in.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `models.DurationField` (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/durationfield-django-models/) and specify any duration, also in the model you need to create a field from which moment to count and either indicate what the timezone is there or save it separately in the field for each record